# Extract the names from raw text

Tags: regex, nlp, text-extraction

I am working on a problem where i have a raw text in which there's a pattern like `Some Name (vs|v.) Some other name` and i want to extract those names i.e.

I TRIED

`(first group) (vs|v.) (second group)`

using regex to catch the words on both sides of vs but that catches only a word and not the complete name and i don't know where to stop while extracting names on both the sides of `vs` as the names are pretty much the same as other text

Any help would be appreciated

text is something like

```
person concerned applies, the Assessing Officer has to issue an appropriate certificate [Cf. 
<em>L. Hirday Narain vs Income Tax Officer, 
</em>(1970) 78 ITR 26(SC) ].
```

so here the regex should catch 
`L. Hirday Narain` and `Income Tax Officer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work with the following Regex:

```
/([\w&;.][\w&;. ]+[\w&;.]) v. ([\w&;. ]+[\w&;.])[ ,<\n.]/gm
```

See live example over here:
https://regex101.com/r/zP8jM0/4

We have two capture groups, divided by the pattern " v. " which must be between the groups to match.

In first capture group we start with: [\w&;.]
This captures one char, which is either \w (= a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _)) or &;.

Then we capture one ore more (+) chars of: [\w&;. ]+
This ist the same group, but with additional " "

At last we capture: [\w&;.]
This captures one char, which is either \w (= a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _)) or &;.

By using char groups without " " at the beginning and the end, we can be sure, that the found namens don't have leading or trailing spaces.

The second capture group (for name 2) works a little bit different.

We start with: [\w&;. ]
This captures multiples chars, which are either \w (= a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) or & ;.

The we end the group with to make sure, it hasn't any trailing spaces: [\w&;.]
This captures one char, which is either \w (= a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _)) or &;.

At last, we have some kind of stop pattern: [ ,<\n.]
This ensures that the name ends before any tags (<) or when a new line starts (\n) or a sentence ends (,.)

Comment: "Nope" isn't correct. Before you edited the question, this was a valid regex. But let me see, what I can do... Also in your sample there is "v." instead of "vs". What do you get normally? "v." or "vs"?

Comment: Updated the regex. Try it.

Comment: Here it worked for the most part except it missed `L.` part of first name and also when i applied it on much larger text it missed other simlar patterns

Comment: Is this even possible in regex ?

Comment: don't you have the names in your code? the question is, why do you need to do it?

Comment: @NEO-xx than just add the "." - see my updated post.

Comment: @netblognet it works 
it misses only one pattern if you see your link
and, that too because of `</a>` tag without space after second name
can you resolve that as well ?

Comment: Great thanks @netblognet would you mind explaining your regex

Comment: Added explanation in my own words. Maybe not the best, but I hope it's understandable.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution in general would be to split the text on `" vs "` as a `delimiter`.

First, extract out the text between tags doing something like this

```
var bigText = "erson concerned applies, the Assessing Officer has to issue an appropriate certificate [Cf.<em>L. Hirday Narain vs Income Tax Officer,\n</em>(1970) 78 ITR 26(SC) ]. ";
var a = "";
var names = [];
bigText.replace(
            /<em>(.*?),\n<\/em>/g,
            function () {
                a = arguments[1];
                names = a.split(/ vs /);
                console.log(names);
            }
);
```

will give you the resulting array `names` as

```
["L. Hirday Narain", "Income Tax Officer"]
```

Comment: The text is not just `something vs something` it's a big para in which i have to find the names on both the side of vs
the only constant part of pattern is `vs`

Comment: Updated please check

Comment: hey this works but the problem is the em tags aren't consistent while surrounding text

Comment: em tags aren't consistent? what do you mean?

Comment: i mean, there might be <em> tag or there might not be in big text raw text

Answer (score 0):

i tried your sample text in notepad++ and was able to get results with following Regex assuming there is a comma after 2nd name

```
(.+?)vs(.+),
```